# Reading full file from Standard Input and Supplying it to a command in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to read contents of a file given from standard input into a script. Any ideas how to do that? 
Basically what I want is:

```
someScript.ksh < textFile.txt
```

Inside the ksh, I am using a binary which will read data from "textFile.txt" if the file is given on the standard input. 
Any ideas how do I "pass" the contents of the given input file, if any, to another binary inside the script?

Comment: I'm not quite getting the question. Does the command accept the filename on the command line or on standard input? If it accepts standard input, then you can just invoke the command from within the script and automatically takes the same input as the script unless you change something. Now if it expects a filename, that's a different matter

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really given us enough information to answer the question, but here are a few ideas.

If you have a script that you want to accept data on *stdin*, and that script calls something else that expects data to be passed in as a filename on the command line, you can take *stdin* and dump it to a temporary file.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp tmpXXXXXX)
cat > $tmpfile
/some/other/command $tmpfile
rm -f $tmpfile
```

(In practice, you would probably use `trap` to clean up the temporary file on exit).

---

If instead the script is calling another command that *also* expects input on *stdin*, you don't really have to do anything special.  Inside your script, *stdin* of anything you call will be connected to *stdin* of the calling script, and as long as you haven't previously consumed the input you should be all set.

E.g., given a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed s/hello/goodbye/
```

I can run:

```
echo hello world | sh myscript.sh
```

And get:

```
goodbye world
```

Comment: Section B is a good example of a shell "wrapper": a script that does not act on any data but just makes sure the conditions are right for another program.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear about what I needed. Actually, I am trying to write a wrapper script for sybase isql command. So that when given an input file it can be loaded without giving all the server parameters.

Comment: Your suggestion gave me idea about how it can be achieved: 
Inside the script I am using this code: 
    TMPSQL= ` cat `
    isql -S${SERVER} -U$UID -P$PASSWD $@ <<!
    $TMPSQL
    go
    !
Where SERVER, UID and PASSWD are being set in the script.